# Cloth simulation is all compressing!

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, workflow, cloth-simulation

Any cloth simulation I do is very strangely compressing, and deform in very abstract and weird way.

[image]

Its bothering me for several days already, and I can't seem to find an answer.

**Please can anybody take a look at my Blend file and help me?**

[image]

Before the Simulation:

[image]

After:

[image]

Actually never mind my bad, I just forgot the way Solidify modifier works. The thickness adds up kinda it doesn't just appear there. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I asked you to remove the solidify modifier was to be sure of what was causing the issue, you can add it in the settings and bake it, but when you add solidify modifier do not increase the thickness to a high amount, I have tested it and it produces the same result if I add it before or after the cloth attribute is added in physics... a thickness of 0.1 to 0.2 should do,..... the plane you used to create your cloth is thin so increase it a little bit in z axis to accommodate some thickness because solidify adds some amount of thickness.